# create the heading title into CSV

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm having the input xml like below:

```
<sect1>
   <title>Intro</title>
   <sect2>
      <title>Purpose</title>
         <sect3>
             <title>Scope</title>
         </sect3>
   </sect2>   
   <sect2>
      <title>Take</title>
   <table><title>Table 1</title></table>
   </sect2>
</sect1>
```

I have created the XSL for the above xml:

```
<xsl:variable name="xmlpath" select="/files/path"/>
    <xsl:variable name="rootLangLoc" select="/files/@xml:lang"/>

    <xsl:variable name="newline"><xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="linebreak"><xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Top Heading,Sub Heading</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$linebreak"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="files/file">
            <xsl:variable name="FullName" select="concat($xmlpath, ., $rootLangLoc, '.xml')"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document($FullName)" mode="csvprocess"/>
        </xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="/sect1/title">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>

        <xsl:for-each select="/sect1/sect2/title">
            <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/sect1/sect2/title"/>


            <xsl:for-each select="/sect1/sect2/sect3/title">
                <xsl:value-of select="$newline"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/sect1/sect2/sect3/title"/>
            </xsl:for-each>

        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
```

I got the CSV output like:

```
Intro
,Purpose
,Take
,,Scope
```

Excepted output would be:

```
Intro
,Purpose
,,Scope
,Take
```

I want all the section title is to be in proper order as per the input xml. I'm getting the output like section 1 title's first and section 2 title's next as like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am guessing correctly the logic that you're trying to apply here, you could do simply:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text>Top Heading,Sub Heading&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="//title ">
        <xsl:value-of select="for $i in 1 to count(ancestor::*) - 1 return ','" separator=""/>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bwdwrS

---

Another way you could use to get the level of the current `title` is:

```
substring-after(name(..), 'sect')
```

Comment: It's working fine. But i want the title of section's(sect1, sect2...) only. It's taking table title also. can you please edit?

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow. What is "table title"? Are you using a different input?

Comment: I have edited the table title in question. please see?

Comment: Try changing `<xsl:for-each select="//title[">`  to `<xsl:for-each select="//title[starts-with(name(..), 'sect')] ">`. Again, I am guessing the logic from the example.